# Приоритет наложение слоёв

Tags: css, css3

Свойство z-index как правило применяется только исключительно к позиционированным элементам (relative, absolute, fixed и т. д.) https://jsfiddle.net/8e1hxkmy/ Вот есть элемент Р и Н1, Р находится под Н1 потому что у Н1 задан приоритет слоя z-index:2; Далее у Р есть вложенный элемент  EM у которого z-index ещё больше чем у H1, но так как ЕМ не позиционированный он не должен налаживаться на Н1 но, если его контейнеру Р присвоить display:flex; так ЕМ сразу начинает налаживаться на H1. Почему такое поведение?

```css
p{
 margin-bottom: -30px;
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    display: flex;
    background: blue;
}
h1{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: green;
}
p em{
    background: red;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
  <p>13231<em>666</em></p>
     <h1>Aaaaa</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это поведение согласно спецификации w3.org.**

Элементы контейнера `Flex` отрисовываются как `inline` элементы, за исключением возможности применять `z-index` даже если `position: static`

> **[4.3. Flex Item Z-Ordering](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting)**
>
> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks [CSS21], except
>   that order-modified document order is used in place of raw document
>   order, and z-index values other than auto create a stacking context
>   even if position is static.

Comment: Т. е. к элементам контейнера flex можно применять z-index ?

Comment: @PeGaS экзакли!

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` применяется не только для позиции, а ко всем гибким элементам. Гибкими элементы делает `position: absolite, fixed, static...` и так же гибким их делает `display: flex`. Приоритетными его блоки становятся потому, что `p` стоит перед `h1`

```css
p{
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    display: flex;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
h1{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: green;
}
p em{
    background: red;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<p>13231<em>666</em></p>
<h1>Aaaaa</h1>
```